# useragent googlebot using selenium

Tags: selenium, user-agent, googlebot, selenium-server

I'm trying to use selenium to invoke my webpage as googlebot. below is my code, but it does redirect the traffic to view webpage as googlebot...Can someone help me to direct my requests to googlebot programmatically?

```
package com.eviltester.captureNetworkTraffic;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumServer;

import com.thoughtworks.selenium.DefaultSelenium;

public class SeleniumTrafficAnalyserExampleTest {

@Test
public void testProfileEvilTester() throws Exception{

    // Start the Selenium Server
    SeleniumServer srvr = new SeleniumServer();
    srvr.start();

    // Create a Selenium Session with captureNetworkTraffic ready
    String site = "...";//My URL 

    DefaultSelenium selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "*iexplore", site);
    selenium.start("addCustomRequestHeader=true");
    selenium.addCustomRequestHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)");

    // open a page to get the traffic
    selenium.open("/us/en_us/");
    selenium.close();
    selenium.stop();
    srvr.stop();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code works as expected

FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.setPreference("general.useragent.override", "Googlebot/2.1+http://www.googlebot.com/bot.html)");

WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);

String site = "http://store.nike.com/us/en_us/";

driver.get(site);